# Joining to a collection in a JPA-QL query 

Tags: java, jpa

I'am using JPA for mapping ,I have this entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "h_pe")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({

public class HPe implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @EmbeddedId
 protected HPePK hPePK;
 @Column(name = "PE_TIMEOUT")
 private Integer peTimeout;
 @Column(name = "PE_STATUS")
 private Boolean peStatus;
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "hPe")
 private Collection<HPesp> hPespCollection;
 @JoinColumn(name = "PE_ENV", referencedColumnName = "ENV_URL", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 @ManyToOne(optional = false)
 private HEnv hEnv;
 @JoinColumn(name = "PE_PLATFORM", referencedColumnName = "PLATFORM_NAME", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 @ManyToOne(optional = false)
 private HPlatform hPlatform;

}
```

I want to write a request JPA like the following(I have wrote it with SQl ),I have tried to write it but I haven't understood how to use PE_ENV because it is the result of OneToMany relationship!

```
select distinct h_env.env_name,h_platform.PLATFORM_NAME
from h_env,h_platform,h_pe
where h_env.ENV_URL=h_pe.PE_ENV
and h_platform.PLATFORM_NAME=h_pe.PE_PLATFORM
and h_platform.PLATFORM_NAME='XXX';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Select e.name, p.name
from HPe hp join hp.hPlatform p join hp.hPespCollection p
where p.name = 'xxx'
```

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#Common_Queries